# How to create an unidirectional OneToMany connections the right way?

Tags: java, hibernate

Question: is this the correct way of creating an unidirectional mapping?

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    List<ProductText> texts;
}

@Entity
public class ProductText {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String text;
    //some more
}
```

This will result in 3 autogenerated tables: `product`, `product_text`, `product_texts (the join table)`.

The `ProductText` rows itself will never be fetched alone. I will always only fetch them in context of selecting the `Product`. There is no `ProductText` that will be assigned to multiple `Products`.

Comment: If the `ProductText` cannot have a `Product` `id` then this is the only way of doing it - with a join table. It's probably more efficient to make it bi-direction and inverse; so that `ProductText` controls the relationship. But it really depends on your use case.

Comment: Could you go a bit into detail *why* it would probably be *more efficient to make it bi-direciton and inverse*, and how this would look like?

Comment: You'll have one less table to join, update, query etc. If the "One" side of the join controls the relationship then it can be updated directly if its parent changes. The way in which join tables are updated can be a little convoluted. [Outdated now but worth a read](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-collections-mostefficientupdate). Seems like a non-inverse `List` is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 1):

More efficient way is to have a `product` column in the `product_text` table; there is no need for a separate join table. So, just specify the [`@JoinColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) for the `@OneToMany` mapping:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "product")
List<ProductText> texts;
```